# How Do I generate pdf from uploaded template in php

Tags: php, templates, export, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I want to generate PDF or Msword that base on a template that I uploaded But I don't know any library or anything about it.
Can you guys recommend me something or where should I start looking?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For template you can use [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/).
This the example from official site:

```php
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
use setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

$pdf = new Fpdi();

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('Fantastic-Speaker.pdf');
$pageId = $pdf->importPage(1, PdfReader\PageBoundaries::MEDIA_BOX);

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useImportedPage($pageId, 10, 10, 90);

$pdf->Output('I', 'generated.pdf');
```

Comment: I wanted to do something like, Upload a template and change some infomation in that, and export to pdf again.

Comment: What the file type of the template?

Comment: Mainly pdf @amiad